# filter blur - blurring the whole background

Tags: html, css, filter, blur

I'm trying to blur the whole background using `-webkit-filter: blur(5px)` etc. It works for the most part but it kind of stops at the border.

How can fix so it's fully blurred?

Thanks

Comment: can you give an example to your problem? I created a fiddle where it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/jap20v8d/ so please give an example to your scenario to see where it is failing

Comment: [here](http://imgur.com/i3UULEA). See the white border where it stops?